# Scanning l3key with document catcodes?

Tags: expl3, catcodes, l3keys

Similar to the way TikZ attempts to use unknown keys as values for the `color` key, I would like to interpret an unknown key as the value for one of my own keys, `decoration` (not to be confused with the key of the same name from TikZ), written using `expl3`.

Naively, I tried using

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  decoration .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_decoration_tl ,
  unknown    .code:n   = {
    \tl_set:NV \l_mymodule_decoration_tl \l_keys_key_tl }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \mymathmacro { O{} m } {
  \mymodule_mathmacro:nn {#1} {#2}
}

\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_mathmacro:nn #1#2 {
  \keys_set:nn { mymodule } {#1}
  #2 \tl_use:N \l_mymodule_decoration_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This works well except that I sometimes will give the unknown key `^2`, as in `$\mymathmacro[^2]{x}$`, intending that the decoration then be a superscript `2`.  Instead, I get as the decoration a `^` character followed by `2`.

Assuming that the problem is catcode assignments, I'm now using

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }

\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  decoration .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_decoration_tl ,
  unknown    .code:n   = {
    \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_mymodule_decoration_tl
      { \char_set_catcode_math_subscript:N _
        \char_set_catcode_math_superscript:N ^ }
     \l_keys_key_tl
  }
}

...

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This works great so far, but my question is this: How do I know I haven't missed important catcode assignments?  What I really want is that the unknown key be scanned as if it was given directly as a value to the `decoration` key.

Also, I've heard that `\tl_rescan:nn` and cousins should be avoided.  Is there a better way for me to write the code for `unknown` than using `\tl_set_rescan:NnV`?

Comment: At the end of section 4 in part XIX of `interface3.pdf`, it's stated that “This information is stored in `\l_keys_key_tl`, and will have been processed by `\tl_to_str:n.`, so the behavior you get is expected. You *can* use `\tl_set_rescan:NnV`, why not? The second argument can be left empty, because the function is called in a normal category code setup. However this is a key *name*, so I don't think you should use it, but rather its value.

Comment: One can argue that perhaps in the case of an unknown key we should take a different approach here. Detokenization makes sense for keys you find as the names have to work inside a `c`-type argument. On the other hand, unknown key names can in principal be used as 'keyless' values. As you observe, this tends to be done mainly for things like colours, where detokenization should be safe. Perhaps raise on LaTeX-L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misusing the key-value system. What gets stored in `\l_keys_key_tl` is a *key name*, not a value, so it's normalized to be a string; quoting the documentation (end of section 4 in part XIX),

> This information is stored in `\l_keys_key_tl`, and will have been processed by `\tl_to_str:n`.

Thus the behavior is expected and I don't think you have a gain by saying

```
$\mymathmacro[^2]{x}$
```

instead of

```
$\mymathmacro[decoration=^2]{x}$
```

For the former syntax, just use a standard optional argument, not the key-value system. A command should take either a key-value list as argument or a list of tokens to be used. Having both possibilities is confusing.

---

If you really insist in using a key name as a value, you can do

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  decoration .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_decoration_tl ,
  unknown    .code:n   =
   {
    \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_mymodule_decoration_tl {} \l_keys_key_tl
   },
}
```

There is no need to specify any category code change in the second argument to `\tl_set_rescan:NnV`, because the tokens will be rescanned under the normal category codes regime, when the function is called, so `^` is a superscript (category 7) and `_` is a subscript (category 8).

Comment: Fair enough.  I do have other key-value pairs that I omitted to simplify the example (e.g., `font=\mathsf` and so on), so just using a single standard optional argument isn't quite an option.  But I get your point: I should either use two separate optional arguments or make the `decoration=` explicit.

Comment: In your above comment, you mention leaving the second argument of `\tl_set_rescan:NnV` empty.  I don't see this in the documentation.  Could you expand on this a bit in your answer?  What exactly does leaving the second argument empty do?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Done; if you don't trust me, try adding `\tl_show_analysis:N \l_mymodule_decoration_tl` between `\l_keys_key_tl` and the closing brace. It requires `\usepackage{l3tl-analysis}`.